Cannot create vpclink and restapi from openapi file in the same cdk/cloudformation sack
I am using OpenAPI with the SpecRestApi cdk construct to create a RestApi. I am creating a vpclink as part of my cdk stack and adding in the
"x-amazon-apigateway-integration": { 
   "type": "http_proxy",
   "connectionType": "VPC_LINK",
   "connectionId": "${Token[TOKEN.16]}" 
}

extension to the OpenApi doc to create a private integration. Currently, the cdk adds the Token placeholder for the connectionId, which represents the physical id of the vpclink. However, this token does not appear to resolve to the vpclink id during cdk deploy and fails:
Unable to put integration on 'GET' for resource at path '/users': Vpc link ${Token[TOKEN.16]} was not found in account xxxx

This is the cdk code:
# Create the VPC Link
link = CustomVpcLink(self, "link",
               description = 'test vpc link', 
               vpc_link_name = 'test-link'
               )   

# Get the VPC Link ID
vpc_link_id = link.vpc_link_id

# Get the directory of the current script
__dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)

# Get the path to the openapi.json file
file_path = os.path.join(__dirname, "..", "assets", "openapi.json")

# Open the OpenAPI file
for path, methods in api_definition['paths'].items():
        for method_name, method in methods.items():
            if 'x-amazon-apigateway-integration' not in method:
                method['x-amazon-apigateway-integration'] = {}
            method['x-amazon-apigateway-integration']['type'] = "http_proxy"
            method['x-amazon-apigateway-integration']['connectionType'] = "VPC_LINK"
            method['x-amazon-apigateway-integration']['connectionId'] = vpc_link_id                        #{"Fn::GetAtt": ["test-link", "VpcLinkId"]}
            method['x-amazon-apigateway-integration']['httpMethod'] = method_name.upper()

# Replace the old OpenAPI file with the updated one that has the AWS integration params
with open(file_path, "w") as f:
    json.dump(api_definition, f, indent=2)

# Create an ApiDefinition CDK object for use with SpecRestApi
api_definition = ApiDefinition.from_asset(file_path)

# Create the SpecRestApi
self.spec_restapi = CustomSpecRestApi(
    self,
    "CustomSpecRestApi",
    api_definition=api_definition
    )

api_definition.bind_after_create(self, self.spec_restapi)

# Create the SpecRestApi only after the VpcLink is created
self.spec_restapi.node.add_dependency(link)     


I have tried embedding cloudformation intrinsic intrinsic functions in the openapi doc as well, but nothing is working.
